# Web worker which uses code from module in an angular app

Tags: angular, web-worker

I have an angular app and I need to use web worker to execute some code, but the code relies on a certain module.

The worker is initialized like this and it works fine if no outer module is needed

```
  var worker = new Worker('data:text/javascript;base64,' + btoa('self.postMessage((' + String(code) + '\n)());'));
```

where `code` is a function ref.

So how can I make this work? preferably without real time loading of the module.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to define a module(file) from your worker and import that outer module you need.
Like this:

outermodule.js:

```
var value = "my value";
module.exports = value;
```

worker.js

```
var value = require('./outermodule');

addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
  const response = `worker response: ${value}` ;
  postMessage(response);
});
```

main thread:
index.js

```
const worker = new Worker('./worker', { type: 'module' });
  worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
    console.log(`got message from worker: ${data}`);
  };
  worker.postMessage('hello');
```

Reading material:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker
2. https://angular.io/guide/web-worker